# How to enable right click functionlity having open link in new tab in angular

Tags: angular, click, routerlink, ctrl

In angular, I want to navigate to the link on staying at the tab and also should enable right click option showing [this popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLALn.png). When I click directly on link, It should open in same tab and when I click on link pressing ctrl key, It should open in new tab.

`<a href='javascript:void(0)' [routerLink]="['/xyz/aaa']" /a>`

If I knew the all link parameters, By using above code I could able to acheive but the parameters in link I get it from API. on click of link I have to trigger an API and then I am supposed to navigate.

I tried

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' [routerLink]="Navigate(data)" /a>
Navigate(data){
   //get xyz from API

   this.router.navigate(["/xyz/home"]);
}
```

but API is geting multiple times, once the page loads as routerLink is async

and I tried this as well

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' [routerLink]="" (click)="Navigate(data)"/a>
Navigate(data){
   //get xyz from API

   this.router.navigate(["/xyz/home"]);
}
```

I could able to navigate in same tab, when I click directly but unable to enable right click fuctionality to get this popup (https://i.stack.imgur.com/db7U2.png) (open link in new tab) or ctrl + click as well

Any suggestions are appreciated...!

Comment: You must have value in `routerLink` attribute. If you don't have href with link in a tag the thing won't work in the browser. So, make sure you printed the URL in a tag

Answer (score 0):

The `routerLink` attribute is required in order for the solution I provided to work. The `routerLink` attribute is used to specify the route to navigate to when the link is clicked.

```
<a [routerLink]="Navigate(data)"> Link </a>
```

You can return the URL from the `Navigate(data)` function.

```
Navigate(data){
  return ["/xyz/home"]
}
```

Comment: But here the issue is `Navigate(data){
// I have to run couple of APIs to get value of xyz
return ["/xyz/home"]}
`
Navigate(data) function is getting triggered multiple times on page load and due to which APIs are also getting fired multiple times. How to over come this issue

Comment: In your example if I write `Navigate(data){console.log(data)}` I see multiple times data getting printed in browser console. Even when I don't click on the link.... This is the issue